# SBT: How to run an annotation processing plugin

Tags: scala, jpa, sbt, querydsl

Does anyone knows how to configure a SBT project to run an annotation processor (APT)? I'm doing some lab on a web project, using some Java tools like QueryDSL, and i need to generate querydsl classes for my JPA model classes, in a similar way QueryDSL Maven plugin does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [play-querydsl](https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl), details of plugin in: `https://github.com/CedricGatay/play-querydsl/blob/master/src/main/scala/QueryDSLPlugin.scala`. You can try to run in on your code, check the line: `Seq("-proc:only", "-processor", "com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor", "-s", outputDirectory.getAbsolutePath))(streams.log)`

Comment: I'll take a look and post the results after some tests. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't get that to work in Scala projects without any java source files -- the "`javac -proc:only`" command fails with "`javac: no source files`"

Answer (score 7):

You could manually run the annotation processor (see `command` below) or implement an SBT task similar to the following:

```
lazy val processAnnotations = taskKey[Unit]("Process annotations")

processAnnotations := {
  val log = streams.value.log

  log.info("Processing annotations ...")

  val classpath = ((products in Compile).value ++ ((dependencyClasspath in Compile).value.files)) mkString ":"
  val destinationDirectory = (classDirectory in Compile).value
  val processor = "com.package.PluginProcessor"
  val classesToProcess = Seq("com.package.Class1", "com.package.Class2") mkString " "

  val command = s"javac -cp $classpath -proc:only -processor $processor -XprintRounds -d $destinationDirectory $classesToProcess"

  failIfNonZeroExitStatus(command, "Failed to process annotations.", log)

  log.info("Done processing annotations.")
}


def failIfNonZeroExitStatus(command: String, message: => String, log: Logger) {
  val result = command !

  if (result != 0) {
    log.error(message)
    sys.error("Failed running command: " + command)
  }
}

packageBin in Compile <<= (packageBin in Compile) dependsOn (processAnnotations in Compile)
```

Update `destinationDirectory`, `processor`, and `classesToProcess` as necessary.

You might also change the "-d" flag to "-s" depending on the type of annotation processor you have (see [options for javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options)).

Comment: how to write it in `sbt.version=0.13.15`?